# Abstract and virtual functions

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, virtual, abstract

I am trying to implement two level inheritance. Currently, there is an abstract class and an inherited class :

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void func();
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void func()
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

I would like to create two specialized instances of class B but I want those functions to be exposed by class A. I am going for,

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void func();
}

public class B : A
{
    public virtual void func();
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void func()
    {
         ........
    }
}

public class D : B
{
    public override void func()
    {
         ........
    }
}
```

This implementation is wrong but that is my intent. How will I implement this ?

Comment: Should `class B` have an implementation for `func()` or not?

Comment: Actually Class B doesnt hv an implementation for func(). I will update the question.

Comment: If it doesn't have an implementation and you do not provide an 'empty' implementation, then `class B` is also abstract (which is fine, unless you need to be able to create a concrete `class B`).

Comment: Class B has other functions that have implementations (Overridden functions)

Comment: Consider `throw NotImplementedException();` for the method in `B`. But it is probably better to make `B` `abstract` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interface instead of abstract class A like this:

```
public interface A
{
    void func();
}
public abstract class B: A
{
    public abstract void func();
}
public class C : B
{
    public override void func()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public class D : B
{
    public override void func()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

May be it helps you.

Comment: You're assuming the OP won't want to instantiate and use class B for other potential properties/methods.

Comment: @AshwinNair: I cant get you please explain your concern?

Comment: I mean you're assuming the OP won't want to use: `var b = new B();`

Comment: I cannot change Class A to interface because this is all part of a factory pattern. The factory class returns generic class A objects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have virtual method without implementation, so instead you should make class `B` abstract, which should make compiler happy:

```
public abstract class B : A
{
}
```

Alternative approach is to add empty method body for function `func`:

```
public class B : A
{
    public virtual void func()
    {
        // function has empty method body
        // it does not do anything, but you can override functionality in derived classes
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the return types. Can we override a overridden function?

Comment: @sethu Yes, you can. Abstract, virtual or overridden functions can all be overridden in derived classes

Comment: If i use override for a overridden function (Class b has public override void func()). In that scenario, the overridden function (Functions in C and D) never get called. Only function in class B is triggered.

Comment: It worked ! I just had to create object of that specific type.